# PHPSTORM_META как указать возвращаемый тип

Tags: php, phpstorm

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#navigate-to-a-metadata-directive

Есть кастомная DI (легаси) что работает так:

```
/** @var SomeClass $settings */  
$settings = DI()->GetSettings(SomeClass::NAME);

$settings instanceof SomeClass = true
SomeClass::NAME - константа, есть в каждом классе
```

Как в .phpstorm.meta.php указать что то что оканчивается на ::NAME должно возвращаться в качеcтве значения

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META
{
    override(DI()->GetSettings(0'::NAME'), type(0));
}
```